# Getting default TextView textColor in Android for current Theme

Tags: android, themes

I'm trying to reset the TextColor of a TextView at runtime. I would like to get the default color for TextView as a `@ColorInt`. I believe that the current Theme knows this.

Here's what I tried:

```
public @ColorInt int getDefaultThemeColor(int attribute) {
    TypedArray themeArray = mContext.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[] {attribute});
    try {
        int index = 0;
        int defaultColourValue = 0;
        return themeArray.getColor(index, defaultColourValue);
    }
    finally {
        themeArray.recycle();
    }
}
```

where attribute is:

- `android.R.attr.textColor`
- `android.R.attr.textColorPrimary`
- `android.R.attr.textColorSecondary`

None of them worked to retrieve the right color. I've also tried to replace the first line of the method with:

```
TypedArray themeArray = mContext.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.AppTheme, new int[] {attribute});
```

I don't want the dirty solution of:

1. getting and storing the textColor of a TextView
2. changing the color to whatever
3. Reset it back to the previously stored value

Any hint?

Comment: if it helps default color for `TextView ` is `#666666`.

Comment: Not sure if you are refering to colors stored in [R.color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#primary_text_dark) like primary text dark, etc.

Comment: @JoséMaría Nope, just the default color for the current Theme.

Comment: @vrundpurohit  I guess the value ca be different if the device manufacturer has a custom theme...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following extension function (using kotlin):

```
@ColorInt
@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
fun Context.getColorResCompat(@AttrRes id: Int): Int {
    val resolvedAttr = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(id, resolvedAttr, true)
    val colorRes = resolvedAttr.run { if (resourceId != 0) resourceId else data }
    return ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)
}
```

And then use it as follow:

```
val defaultText = context.getColorResCompat(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary)
```

Comment: The resource used by TextView seems to be textColorSecondary, not textColorPrimary

Comment: For me, `textColorSecondary` resulted in a slightly greyish color, different from the default `TextView` color, which was black. `textColorPrimary` yielded the correct black result.

Text colors were not defined explicitly in the `Theme`, system default was used (Android 11).

Answer (score 2):

The following code gives you a ColorStateList, which is not exactly what you asked for, but might be also applicable in the context where you need it:

```
TypedArray themeArray = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{android.R.attr.textColorSecondary});
ColorStateList textColorSecondary = themeArray.getColorStateList(0);
```